Problem with Uri in the Send an HTTP request to Sharepoint because of the language?
I have found an article to put this Uri-string in the Send an HTTP request to SharePoint connector:
_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Site%20Pages')/items('ID')/CanvasContent1
Only I am Dutch and my sitepages is called Sitepagina's
So i have change it a couple of difirent ways but still getting the error:
_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Sitepagina's')/items('ID')/CanvasContent1
_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Sitepaginas')/items('ID')/CanvasContent1
_api/web/lists/GetByTitle("Sitepagina's")/items('ID')/CanvasContent1
What is the right syntax?

Try using this and let me know if it works for you: _api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Sitepagina''s')/items('ID')/CanvasContent1. Basically, you have to escape single quotes (') by using single quotes 2 times like ''.

I wrote a blog post about this a few years ago
https://blog.icefire.ca/blogs/post/how-to-make-sharepoint-api-calls-language-independent
GetByTitle is always used in API calls written by people whose only language is English, but it is not language independent
In your case you are only dealing with one language, so the most likely way for Dutch is to URLencode the apostrophe, replacing it with %27
